# Adding items to nested lists

Tags: python

I am new to python and struggling with adding values to nested lists. I have a list that contains 6 values. My lists of lists contains 3 lists and I would like to add the values the 6 values in such a way that the 1 value goes to the 1 list, 2 value to 2nd list, 3rd value to 3 list. Then I would like to continue looping so that the 4 value goes to the first list, 5 value to second list and 6 value to 3rd list. In the end I want to end up with a list of three lists which each contains 2 items. I am struggling to get anything wise to run. Can someone help me on this, thank you!

Comment: Hi Tomas, it's better to provide an example list that other people can easily copy. It's also a good idea to give the expected output and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the position of the item in the list of values (modulo the total number of target lists) to get the right list to append to.

```
lists = [[], [], []]                                                    
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]                                             
for i, x in enumerate(values): 
     lists[i % len(lists)].append(x)
```

Or use `itertools.cycle` and `zip`:

```
from itertools import cycle                                            
lists = [[], [], []]                                                   
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]                                            
for x, l in zip(values, cycle(lists)): 
    l.append(x)
```

Both ways, `lists` ends up as `[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]`.

---

In case you want more "regular" loops, you can also use `range` with `start`, `stop` and `step` parameters to create the sublists and then add those to the list of lists:

```
n = 3
lists = []
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]                                             
for k in range(n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(k, len(values), n):
        lst.append(values[i])
    lists.append(lst)
```

The same also works in a quite readable one-list list copmrehension:

```
lists = [[values[i] for i in range(k, len(values), 3)] for k in range(3)]
```

Or using `zip`, `map` and `iter`, in case you want to show off:

```
lists = list(map(list, zip(*zip(*[iter(values)]*3))))
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! Is it possible to do it by using regular for loops?

Comment: What's not 'regular' about the for-loops in these examples?

Comment: I mean using for example multiple for loops to first create like "inner list" and then appending these inner lists to one "outer list". This was the approach I tried to take when building this.

Answer (score 0):

```
# list with 6 items
# each item in the list has an index/position;

#          0         1       2         3        4      5
cars = ['Subaru', 'Audi', 'Honda', 'Toyota', 'BMW', 'Mazda']

# two empty lists

first_3 = [] # for first 3 items of the "cars" list
last_3 = [] # for last 3 items of the "cars" list


#          0   1  2
finallist=[[],[],[]] # a list with three empty lists inside a list


for car in cars:
    # if the index/position of the car in the "cars" list is below 3
    # add the car to the end of the "first_3" list
    
    if cars.index(car) < 3:
          first_3.append(car)
          
    # if the index/position of the car in the "cars" list is above 2
    # add the car to the end of the "last_3" list
    
    if cars.index(car) > 2:
          last_3.append(car)


# loop the cars in the "first_3" list

for car in first_3:
    
    # get the index of the car in that list
    car_pos = first_3.index(car)
    
    # reference the list with the index "car_pos"
    # i.e - if car_pos is 2, that would be the last list inside of "finallist"
    
    finallist[car_pos].append(car) # append the car
    
    
# loop the cars in the "last_3" list and do the same thing
for car in last_3:
    car_pos = last_3.index(car)
    finallist[car_pos].append(car)


# print the final list
print(finallist)
```

Comment: Did this work? Because I could try again to correct if ive done something wrong?

Comment: Glad that it helped. I'd appreciate it if you 'accept' my answer by clicking the green tick on the left and maybe upvoting?

Comment: `for car in first_3: car_pos = first_3.index(car)` This is super-inefficient, and it won't work if there are any duplicate elements. Instead, use `for car_pos, car in enumerate(first_3):`. (Also, I did not try to understand this in full, but it seems way more complicated than necessary.)